# What options are available for collaborative task management?

Tags: collaboration, tasks

I'm trying to figure a way for our small team to collaborate on to-do lists on projects and otherwise. We have tried Basecamp and a bunch of similar 'project management'/'collaboration' apps, but they seem to overkill for simple todo list sharing and management. We like Remember The Milk, but it is good only for individual lists.

Any ideas on a free/cheap alternative that's simple and just powerful enough to keep a small team of designers/developers productive?

Answer (score 1):

[Teambox](https://teambox.com/) might fit the bill.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I started using **[Remember the Milk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/)**. It's a **very simple** task manager that has resulted in me becoming **much more productive** in the last month.

Sure, I work alone, but I showed RTM to my dad and he has started using it with his team - they all love it. Try it out and see if you like it!

Comment: Hmm... I think I should revisit the sharing part again. Wasn't very impressed the last time I used it though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one more: [bettermeans](http://bettermeans.com). Review at [The Next Web](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2010/11/04/try-this-better-means-a-democratic-open-approach-to-teamwork/).

Answer (score 1):

[Sandglaz](http://sandglaz.com) might fit your needs. It is collaborative and free. We made it, use it and like it.

We built the application because we did not find anything that we like using.

Answer (score 1):

[HyperOffice](http://www.hyperoffice.com/online-project-management/) is an option you may want to consider. It is very feature rich - task scheduling, dependencies, Gantt charts, project spaces, document collaboration, workflows etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Trac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trac)? Its the easiest solutions for collaborating I have used.
[Google wave](http://wave.google.com) can also be used as a collaboration app - I used it for list sharing but it was just too much of a unpolished solution at that time.

Then there is [Microsoft Sharepoint](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com). But its not cheap.

Comment: I tried using Trac a while back, but it is very heavily geared towards the programming side of things. Will try giving it another shot maybe.

Comment: @shivk - Google Wave is dead!

Comment: @itsaboutcode - it is NOW! I know :)

Answer (score 0):

if you tried basecamp, have you tried http://tadalist.com/ by the same company?  Its just todo-lists and it supports basic sharing.

Answer (score 0):

We use (and made!) [Lean-to](http://Lean-to.com). While it has a slant towards agile software project tracking because of the language like (stories and bugs) we have taken great pains to make sure it has remained simple and fun to use. Plus we're always open to suggestions to how we can improve it. (Notice I didn't say we're open to adding a bunch of new features though, as more isn't always better.).

Answer (score 0):

I like [Google Tasks](http://mail.google.com/tasks/canvas).

The main reason for this is the keyboard controls for moving up and down / indenting tasks.

It's not built for collaboration, but there is a `refresh` button to update the list manually.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [manymoon](https://www.manymoon.com/auth/showAboutUs), their free version might fit your needs:

> Manymoon is a social productivity tool
>   that makes it simple to get work done
>   online:
>
> - Anything - you can use Manymoon for whatever you need to accomplish:
>     launching a new product, planning an
>     event or building a house.
> - Anyone - Manymoon is simple enough for anyone to use since there's no
>     training or setup required.
> - Anywhere - Manymoon can be used with people inside and outside of your
>     organization. And since it's online
>     all you'll need is an internet
>     connection to get working!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Action Method: http://actionmethod.com/

I can't give a review, haven't used it, but it seems like you're looking for something less "project management" and more simplistic and focused towards to-do's or "Action steps" as they call them. It's built for teams, and intended for creatives.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Trello](https://trello.com/). It's free and easy.